# WebStorm HTML run on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, debugging, webstorm

I download new version of WebStorm and all my config was deleted; now I don't remember what is my old options/config...

In old version when I click on Chrome mini icon my website started. I found solution but on every new project that I create I need to do the same (create new config again)... this is boring. Please tell me how to config WebStorm to run Chrome in every of my projects.

[image]

[image]

Comment: **1)** *"I download new version of WebStorm and all my config was deleted"* That's very odd -- don't remember seeing this myself. **2)** I'm not sure what exactly you need here. Are you talking about Browsers panel (based on circled area on your 2nd screenshot) ? Or (most likely) you're talking about Run/Debug Configurations (that drop down box). Run/Debug Configurations are per project .. so you have to create it again.

Answer (score 0):

All webstorm settings are stored under the .idea folder in the root of every project you open in webstorm. So you can get your settings from any older project, by just copy/pasting that folder to your current project. Also for more details on IDE setup for default as well as project specific, follow [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html) and [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exporting-and-importing-settings.html) link